# Client Side Port Detection

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I have written a two separate executable file of Server and client in C. Both executable given IP/port via command line .To establish connection I give same port number to both side .

Now I want to Multi thread my Code .Right now I am specifying port number on which server should listen. But after multi thread,Suppose 5 thread want connection on five different port number. How can I multi thread client so that it automatically detect the port number of required connection.or can any other dynamic technique ??

Comment: Are you wanting the server to listen on 5 ports?  It can listen on 1 port and service 5 clients simultaneously.  Do you want 1 client app to create 5 connections to the server, each in a separate thread? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: My goal is to establish 5 connection using 5 different port ..Since client is listening on a single port ..how can I establish server connection with different port ..Here I am struck,,,

Comment: You are not explaining yourself very well.  A **client** does not listen, it connects.  You can have multiple clients that are bound to different **local** ports (and you should let the OS pick those ports for you) connecting to the same **remote** port that the **server** is listening on.  The server only needs to listen on one port, but it can accept multiple clients on that one port.

Comment: its means while I am listening on port 9999 on one side I can accept connection with IP/9998/9997/9996 also ...

Comment: That is still an ambiguous statement. "*listening ... on one side*", so you want the *other* side to accept connections? Then it has to open its own listening ports. Or you want the server to accept connections on all those ports? Then it has to open multiple listening sockets, one per port.

Comment: This discussion is going nowhere.  Please rewrite the question and add more details, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

> To establish connection I give same port number to both side .

Why? It isn't necessary, and using a fixed client-side port can only be counterproductive.

> Right now I am specifying port number on which server should listen. But after multi thread,Suppose 5 thread want connection on five different port number.

No problem.

> How can I multi thread client so that it automatically detect the port number of required connection.

There is no problem here to solve. Don't specify the client-side port number: the system will give you a free one.

Comment: You are assuming the client-side port parameter is being used to specify the client's local port binding, rather than specifying the server port to connect to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am indeed. That is the only sense I can make of this strange question, and specifically it's the only way in which multiple client threads could cause a problem. Your interpretation?

Comment: I interpret it as the OP wanting to connect 5 client threads to 5 different server ports.  But that is why I asked the OP to clarify the requirements.  The question as asked is ambiguous.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In either case there is no problem here to solve. But if you don't know what the question means you can't possibly know the assumption this answer is wrong.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong, and I didn't downvote it.  I was merely stating an observation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with your observation, it's quite correct. The downvote can take care of itself. In many cases they are to be worn with pride.